# Object.assign method will change the origin object property - JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I found a curious thing about `Object.assign()`:

```js
const B = {
    k1: 'b',
    k2: 'bb',
    treedata: [{
        children: ['g']
    }]
}

var A = Object.assign({}, B);
A.treedata[0].children = [1];
console.log(B)
```

As you can see, after `Object.assign()`, changing object `A` will also change object `B`. Why does this happen and how can you avoid this?

Comment: Nothing to do with ReactJS, this is how JavaScript works (and Ruby, and Python...).

Comment: I see, I am doing a react practice, sorry for the tag.

Comment: `Object.assign` only copies properties into a new object. If a property is a reference to another object, like in your case `treedata` is, then `Object.assign` copies a reference, thus objects A and B point to the same `treedata`.

Comment: you can read here also to be clear about Object.assign()

https://osmangoni.info/posts/when-object-assign-is-risky/

Comment: The explanation and answer to this issue is mentioned here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign - under the title "warning for deep clone"

Answer (score 6):

You need to parse and strigify object and then use `object.assign`,
like this `var A = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(B)));`, so that the original object dont change

Check out the snippet

```js
const B = {
k1 : 'b', 
k2 : 'bb', 
treedata : [{ title: 'title', key: -1, fieldName: '', from: -1, to: -1, children: ['g'] }]
}

var A = Object.assign({}, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(B))); 

A.treedata[0].children = [1];
alert(B.treedata[0].children);
```

Comment: thanks Aravind! that helps a lot.

Comment: @charleschen ready to help anytime

Comment: "need to parse and stringify" - no, you just need to deep copy. "parse and stringify" is one way to do that (and not the best one, given its limitations). Please refer instead to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

Comment: @Amadan can you describe deep copy? I really want to know the simple solution.

Comment: There is no simple solution, since there is no native deep copy in JavaScript. The problems with JSON route is it ican't copy circular structures, and can't copy anything that isn't a JSON primitive. I already linked the canonical Stack Overflow thread that deals with deep copy in JavaScript. (Also see [Wikipedia on Object copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copying) to understand the problem.)

Comment: @Amadan Ok, I have seen the link just now, thanks again!